# Mixing ByteString parsing and network IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell

## Background

I'm trying to write a client for a binary network protocol.
All network operations are carried out over a single TCP connection, so in that sense
the input from the server is a continuous stream of bytes.
At the application layer, however, the server conceptually sends a packet on the
stream, and the client keeps reading until it knows the packet has been received
in its entirety, before sending a response of its own.

A lot of the effort needed to make this work involves parsing and generating
binary data, for which I'm using the Data.Serialize module.

## The problem

The server sends me a "packet" on the TCP stream.
The packet is not necessarily terminated by a newline, nor is it of a predetermined
  size.
It *does* consist of a predetermined number of fields, and fields generally begin
  with a 4 byte number describing the length of that field.
With some help from Data.Serialize, I already have the code to parse a ByteString
  version of this packet into a more manageable type.

I'd love to be able to write some code with these properties:

1. The parsing is only defined once, preferably in my Serialize instance(s).
   I'd rather not do extra parsing in the IO monad to read the correct number of bytes.
2. When I try to parse a given packet and not all the bytes have arrived yet, lazy
   IO will just wait for the extra bytes to arrive.
3. Conversely, when I try to parse a given packet and all its bytes *have* arrived
   IO does not block anymore.  That is, I want to read just enough of the stream
   from the server to parse my type and form a response to send back.  If the IO
   blocks even after enough bytes have arrived to parse my type, then the client
   and server will become deadlocked, each waiting for more data from the other.
4. After I send my own response, I can repeat the process by parsing the next type
   of packet I expect from the server.

So in brief,
**is it possible to leverage my current ByteString parsing code in combination
  with lazy IO to read exactly the right number of bytes off the network?**

## What I've Tried

I tried to use lazy ByteStreams in combination with my Data.Serialize instance, like
so:

```
import Network
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Serialize

data MyType

instance Serialize MyType

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  h <- connectTo server port
  hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
  inputStream <- L.hGetContents h
  let Right parsed = decodeLazy inputStream :: Either String MyType
  -- Then use parsed to form my own response, then wait for the server reply...
```

This seems to fail mostly on point 3 above: it stays blocked even after a sufficient
number of bytes have arrived to parse MyType.  I strongly suspect this is because
ByteStrings are read with a given *block size* at a time, and `L.hGetContents` is
waiting for the rest of this block to arrive.  While this property of reading an
efficient blocksize is helpful for making efficient reads from disk, it seems to be
getting in my way for reading just enough bytes to parse my data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something is wrong with your parser, it is too eager. Most likely it need the next byte after the message for some reason. `hGetContents` from `bytestring` doesn't block waiting for the whole chunk. It uses `hGetSome` internally.

I created simple test case. The server sends "hello" every second:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO
import Network

port :: Int
port = 1234

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  s <- listenOn $ PortNumber $ fromIntegral port
  (h, _, _) <- accept s

  let loop :: Int -> IO ()
      loop 0 = return ()
      loop i = do
        hPutStr h "hello"
        threadDelay 1000000
        loop $ i - 1
  loop 5

  sClose s
```

The client reads the whole contents lazily:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import System.IO
import Network

port :: Int
port = 1234

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  h <- connectTo "localhost" $ PortNumber $ fromIntegral port
  bs <- BSL.hGetContents h
  BSL.putStrLn bs
  hClose h
```

If you try to run both of then, you'll see the client printing "hello" every seconds. So, the network subsystem is ok, the issue is somewhere else -- most likely in your parser.

Comment: +1 Very nice and convincing test case.  Oddly, it is not an extra byte I'm expected at the end of the packet, but rather a field in the middle which seems to be problematic...